# How can I get 2 finger scrolling to work?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, touchpad, multi-touch, focaltech

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and for some reason I can't scroll with 2 fingers.

I don't have an option to add it in settings:

[image: Settings dialog]

I tried installing Synaptic Package Manager and using that to enable it but that didn't work.

The last method I tried was installing `focaltech-dkms`. I rebooted, but again, nothing changed.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install focaltech-dkms
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Here is my Xinput:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 FocalTech FocalTech Touchpad in mouse emulation mode id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

How can I get it to work?

Output for `uname -a`:

```
Linux vlad-X550JX 3.19.0-22-generic #22~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 17 10:03:13 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output for `dkms status`:

```
bcmwl, 6.30.223.248+bdcom, 3.16.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
bcmwl, 6.30.223.248+bdcom, 3.19.0-22-generic, x86_64: installed
focaltech, 1.5~trusty1: added
psmouse, elantech-x551c, 3.19.0-22-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `uname -a` terminal command.

Comment: And also add `dkms status` command. The touchpad WILL work with this driver ;-)

Comment: What laptop model (and touchpad version) are you using? You could possibly contribute to the bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1372609) as well if you don't find any solutions

Comment: @Wilf The bug has been reported and already fixed for 15.10. It won't be fixed for current 14.04, but my ppa (hanipouspilot) can be used as a workaround. But as soon as there is `linux-generic-lts-wily` it will be fixed in 14.04 too.

Comment: @Pilot6 ok... will trusty be eventually fixed anyway as it is LTS?

Comment: @Wilf In next HWE kernel. 4.0 has it already. 4.2 is with my finger width patch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is very simple. You installed a wrong Elantech driver first.

This can be fixed by running

```
sudo dkms remove psmouse/elantech-x551c --all
sudo apt-get install --reinstall focaltech-dkms
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Comment: Thx man :D. It works :)

Comment: @DumitruVlad Did you install Elantech from a deb file, or ppa, or what? It makes sense to remove it too.

Comment: I love you both guys, for the question and the answer that fixed everything =D
(But for some reason dkms did not output `psmouse` or `elantech-x551c` on the last line)

Comment: @deb0ch That is because you did not install the wrong Elantech driver.